# Cordova plugin network information not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have followed https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/ but it is not triggering when connecting or disconnecting from the network. Not in browser, dev app and not in phone.

I have checked this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-plugin-network-information-not-working/99271 and check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9nVMSMimRQ

This is my dev environment

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.0
Angular Core: 5.2.11
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
Node: 10.13.0
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a bit of code base of what you have done for more help.

Also add your code under platform ready and test.

*Import platform service before doing this.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        //Code
});
```

Comment: I have already tried this inside "app.components.ts" where we have "this.platform.ready().then(()" ... but not worked :(